# Unable to find option to create a CDN in the new Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I'm trying to create an Azure CDN and cannot find the option to do in the new Azure portal.

According to other sources, there is supposed to be a CDN option under the New -> App Services menu like so:

[image]

But when I log into the portal, this CDN option is missing.  This is what I see:

[image]

Does this have anything to do with my subscription?  I'm using a "3-month Free Trial".

Updating to include a screen shot of my left pane options.  No CDN!

[image]

Comment: This clearly just recently changed.  My subscription doesnt have it either and i'm pay as you go.  There was some documentation that indicated it might be an add on, but its not in the add on/store list either.

Comment: This option wasn't in the left pane of my subscription last week but I see the CDN option now.

Comment: Yep - CDN option appears to be publicly available for all customers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally have the answer why the CDN menu option doesn't appear.

The following from Windows Azure Technical support:

"We’re in the process of building out our next generation Windows Azure Content Delivery Network (CDN) architecture, and during this time we are no longer accepting new CDN customers.

With the CDN functionality having recently transitioned to the new Azure management portal, we have enabled it automatically only for customers who were using CDN in the old management portal, so they can continue to manage their CDN configurations. For everyone else, the CDN feature is not enabled in the new portal.

We highly encourage you to wait until we’re ready building our next generation Azure CDN service."

Comment: Wow
I wish they made this more clear in the portal, been trying to figure this out for 2 days until I found this.

Comment: FYI - I was able to contact Azure support and request to have them enable CDN for me.

Comment: i might try doing that its not high priority i was going to use it to host some SVG files while in development since the default cassini server is broken in this respect i found a workaround for it through the CassiniDev project

Comment: FYI - It appears as though CDN option just recently became available in the portal for all customers.

Answer (score 0):

Should be on the left menu - but then this is an enterprise account: [image] and just confirmed there is no CDN option on my personal account - hmmmm...

Comment: So, its enterprise only now? is that what you're saying?

Comment: This is the first I've heard about Azure enterprise accounts.  I wonder if I can convert a personal account to an enterprise account.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning

As far as I know their is no 'Enterprise' account, I have multiple logins ranging from MSDN, partners etc and all have the same features.  The only difference is when you register for preview services.

On the left hand side in the new portal (light blue bar ) you should see the following items -

All Items
Web Sites
Virtual Machines
Mobile Servces
Cloud Services
SQL Databases
Storage
HDInsight
Media Services
Service Bus
Cache
Recover Services
SQL Reporting
CDN ***************************
Networks
Traffic Manager
Management Services
Active Directory
Add-Ons

Do you see the same, can you see CDN highlighted above

Shane

Comment: Thanks Shane - I don't see CDN in this left pane.  Just included a screen shot in my original post.